# Extend the execution of file from main.ts

Tags: typescript

I have some typescript code in main.ts and some more code in another file extend.ts. Is it possible to continue execution after completion of main.ts which is the entry point for the webpack --watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place code in extend.ts in function, import it in main.ts and call.

```
import { extend } from "./extend";

// ... Do main logic

extend();
```